# Here Maps Calculate Matrix API returns "The request is missing the app_id and app_code parameters." error

Tags: here-api, distance-matrix

I'm trying to get distances for an origin-destination matrix using the following call using an API Key:

```
https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?apiKey=[API Key Here]&start0=35.04672,-85.30947&start1=39.766998.49461&destination0=39.10344,-94.58311&destination1=39.76691,-86.14996&destination2=29.42458,-98.49461&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
```

But it is returning this error in the response details: "The request is missing the app_id and app_code parameters. They must both be passed as query parameters. If you do not have app_id and app_code, please obtain them through your customer representative or at [http://developer.here.com/myapps."](http://developer.here.com/myapps.%22)

But the documentation here says I can use either ApiKey or App_code and App_id. https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-matrix.html

Why doesn't it work with the apiKey?

Answer (score 0):

The base url you are using is incorrect, please replace it with https://matrix.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json to use it with API key.

https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json will work with APPid and APPcode.

For more help on the same, please refer to the example at https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/routing/one-to-many-matrix-routing

Comment: That worked. Thank you. However now I am getting "These credentials do not authorize access" error on my call. Even though I put a credit card for billing purposes. Do you know if I need to do anything else?